# Run async tasks in SignalR

Tags: asynchronous, signalr

I have a dashboard type app, that needs to continuously fetch data from literally hundreds of Atom feeds. The current Webforms implementation is using `async` to build the complete page, using hundreds of threads per request (works fine, as the hardware and network are really fast and there are few users). What would be a good way to architect a SignalR replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SignalR with KnockoutJS for an easy push to UI solution in a web environment.

There are several full solutions over the web like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U) and [that](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/mvc-3-signalr-knockout-real-time-notifications), which have helped me a lot.

This way you can build a page quickly and continue pushing to it while there is still data or new data appearing. using Knockout at the client side will allow you to push the received data straight into the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example here with a progress report :

[https://github.com/dragouf/SignalR.Progress](http://goo.gl/S95MW4)

[image]